# What will happen if assign a pointer an integer value in C ??

Tags: c

```
/*Suppose we initiate a pointer;*/
int *y;
y=36;
/*Is this allowed in C??*/
/* If it is, what will happen if we write to this;*/
*y= 100; 
/*And if its not, then why ?*/
```

Also please explain how this works in memory allocation.

Comment: I see no evidence of any research here.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: @JohnLedbetter: Since the behavior is undefined, giving it a try will not completely answer the question.

Comment: What compiler warnings do you get?

Comment: I use code blocks with mingw compiler, I had no compiling error.

Comment: However, there was runtime error.
'#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *y;
    y = 56;
    printf("%d %u", *y, y);
}
'
Thats the code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did some, though I was not satisfied with what I found, so was looking some detailed explanation.

Comment: Then you should have done _more_!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *cannot* assign an integer value to a pointer object in C.

There is one special case where you can *appear* to do so. A constant `0` (or more generally, an integer constant expression with the value zero) is a null pointer constant. But even in that case, the value is implicitly converted to a null pointer of the appropriate type, and it's that null pointer value, not an integer value `0`, that will be stored in `y`.

```
int *y;
y = 36;
```

The assignment is a *constraint violation*. That means that any conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic message for a program that contains it. Basically it means that the assignment is illegal (though the C standard doesn't call it that). It makes about as much sense as

```
double x = "hello, world";
```

In very old versions of C, before the language was standardized, assigning arbitrary integer values to pointers was commonly permitted. Because of this, many compilers will permit such assignments and merely print a warning rather than a fatal error message. The lesson here is not that it's not a serious error. The lesson is that compiler warnings (at least some of them) should be assumed to be very nearly as serious as fatal error messages.

Now what you *can* do is explicitly convert an integer value to a pointer type, using a cast:

```
y = (int*)36;
```

As the standard says, the result of such a conversion

> is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not
>   point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap
>   representation.

If you attempt either to read or to write the object indicated by `*y`, your program's behavior is undefined. *If you're lucky*, it will crash with an error message. If you're unlucky, it may appear to behave "correctly".

In the extremely unlikely event that you happen to know that there's an `int` object that you can access at machine address `36` (more likely expressed as `0x24`), that would be the way to access it.

Unless you're doing very low-level programming on an embedded system, it's nearly certain that there is no such accessible `int` object at that address.

Bottom line: Don't do that. If your compiler lets you get away with it, it's really not doing you any favors. Find out what options to use with your compiler to cause it to be more strict.

Comment: You do can assign it... but nothing good comes from that road. Most of the times (always?) you will get Segmentation fault when changing the pointed memory location.

Comment: @SlySherZ: Are you saying that you can assign an integer value to a pointer object? As my answer explains, you can't. The integer value must be converted to the pointer type before it can be stored in a pointer object.

Comment: I ran the code and it worked. Try it here: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php
Just got a warning about it

Comment: @SlySherZ: Yes, and I explained that too. What appears to be an assignment of an integer value to a pointer object (a) is a constraint violation, so a compiler is allowed (but unfortunately IMHO not required) to reject it, and (b) must *convert* the integer value to the pointer type before storing it in the pointer object.